# How to get SVG path data of TopoJSON feature without adding it to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, geojson, topojson

I have a special case for which I do not want to add my generated path of a topojson file to the DOM, but rather only get the generated `d` attribute (the SVG path).

So I usually did something like this:

```
let features = feature(landmass, landmass.objects.land).features

        let projection = d3.geoAzimuthalEqualArea()
            .center([180, -180])
            .fitSize([width, height], { type: "FeatureCollection", features: features })

        let path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection)

        g.selectAll("#landmass")
            .data(features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("id", "landmass")
            .attr("d", path);
```

But I actually just want the `features` to be translated to the path using the chosen `geoPath`, without adding any svg object to the DOM.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @altocumulus I cannot check this right now, but if this works then create an answer and I will select it as the correct answer once I can test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3's docs on the geographic [path generators](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#paths) have you covered (emphasis mine):

> The geographic path generator, [d3.geoPath](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#geoPath), is similar to the shape generators in d3-shape: **given a GeoJSON geometry or feature object, it generates an SVG path data string** or renders the path to a Canvas.

You can pass a GeoJSON feature into the path generator and have it create the *path data*—i.e. the path commands—which are then assigned to the `d` property of the `<path>` element. This is basically what happens when coding

```
.data(features)
// ... enter, append, etc...
.attr("d", path);
```

This statement can be rewritten as:

```
.data(features)
// ... enter, append, etc...
.attr("d", d => path(d));
```

or, even more explicitly:

```
.data(features)
// ... enter, append, etc...
.attr("d", feature => path(feature));
```

Looking at the latter code snippet it becomes clear that D3—via its data binding means—creates a `<path>` element for every feature and passes that feature, i.e. the datum bound the the `<path>` element, to the path generator `path` to create the `d` property's path command string.

With this knowledge you can easily create the path data strings for all your features without creating any DOM nodes:

```
const pathData = features.map(feature => path(feature));
```

More concisely, you can just pass the generator function to `.map()`:

```
const pathData = features.map(path);
```